# Apex DML won't recognise variable that SOQL does

Tags: salesforce, apex, soql, dml

I am new to Salesforce Development, I have tested a similar query to this in a sandbox Org which worked, however when trying to update records in the live Org I am having some issues.

The issue and context is as follows: 
I am trying to update the 'Record Type' field of certain Job records through Apex DML.  I have opened the Developer Console and run a query:

```
SELECT Name, GW_Volunteers__Campaign__c, RecordtypeId FROM GW_Volunteers__Volunteer_Job__c WHERE GW_Volunteers__Campaign__c = '7010O000001P2XIQA0' and RecordTypeId = null LIMIT 5
```

This works fine and will show me the first 5 job records where there is no assigned record type, which is what I want to update.

The problem is when I am opening "execute anonymous" window and entering this code:

```
GW_Volunteers__Volunteer_Job__c [] bjobs = [
SELECT Name, GW_Volunteers__Campaign__c, RecordTypeId FROM GW_Volunteers__Volunteer_Job__c WHERE GW_Volunteers__Campaign__c = '7010O000001P2XIQA0' and RecordTypeId = null LIMIT 5];
bjobs.RecordTypeId='0120O000000LAY6QAO';
update bjobs;
```

I keep getting the following error:

> Line: 3, Column: 11 Variable does not exist: RecordTypeId

Unless I have missed something very obvious, I cannot figure out why this is happening. Since it recognizes that variable in the query fine and a similar query (where I also updated the RecordTypeId) in the sandbox worked.

Thank you, 
YH

Comment: If it works, then please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is, you cannot assign `bjobs.RecordTypeId='0120O000000LAY6QAO';`. You know, `bjobs` is an array of `GW_Volunteers__Volunteer_Job__c`.

So, what you need to do is,

```
GW_Volunteers__Volunteer_Job__c [] bjobs = [
SELECT Name, GW_Volunteers__Campaign__c, RecordTypeId FROM GW_Volunteers__Volunteer_Job__c WHERE GW_Volunteers__Campaign__c = '7010O000001P2XIQA0' and RecordTypeId = null LIMIT 5];

for(GW_Volunteers__Volunteer_Job__c job : bjobs)
{
   job.RecordTypeId='0120O000000LAY6QAO';  
}

update bjobs;
```

Hope, this will work.